# Is it a bad idea to have large number of static variable instances?

Tags: c++, graph

I'm working on a weighted graph with nodes having the following properties:

- node Index
- node Weight
- node Neighbors (pointers to Neighbor Nodes)
- corresponding neighbor Weights (edge Weights)

Now edge Weights can be modified by two nodes that are connected by the edge. So, I believe the edge Weights should be a static variable in my Node Class. However, the graph may be very large and I was wondering if using static variables would be a good idea? (It just doesn't feel right)

Comment: I think your intuition is correct; it's not right. You should have a different weight instance per edge. It can have a good default, but you'll probably want different weights across edges in the future.

Comment: Are you aware of http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/graph/doc/ ?

Comment: @AndyG I want two nodes to share an edge weight. Say i have two nodes A and B and an edge between them, if i update the weight of edge through node A then I would also want node B to detect that change and update accordingly.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Thanks, that clears up a lot of concepts :)

Comment: Check out the flyweight design pattern. The nodes can share a reference to the edge.